# dalvikvm is not showing LOGD messages of JIT Options

Tags: android, jit

I have made some minor changes to /dalvik/vm/interp/Jit.cpp 
(wrote some LOGD messages) and built dalvikvm using 
                       $make dalvikvm 
     and the build was successful and got the executable in /out/ 
target/product/generic/system/bin/dalvikvm. 
     Now i started an emulator and pushed dalvikvm into /data and 
executed a sample java program (with some 30 loops) using 
                       $/data/dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:/system/ 
framework/core.jar -classpath /data/CmdLine.jar TestAppActivity 
     (created CmdLine.jar from sample program by following 
instructions given in http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/command-line-java-on-dalvikvm/ 
) 
     now when i check the logcat there is no messages which i have 
written using LOGD is displayed. Do we need to add any option to 
dalvikvm command line to enable JIT? what could be the problem here? 
Thanks

Comment: actually i enabled jit and when i check with /data/dalvikvm -help it shows Configured with: debugger profiler hprof jit(armv7-a) show_exception=1
what could be the problem why the logs are not appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Jit is enabled by default if you are using android version above 2.2 i suppose. Your problem is the profiling of JIT has to be enabled in dvm. This can be don by looking into dalvikvm --help .... I think dalvikvm -Xjitprofile -Xjitverbose should do and before that export your environment variable to log the message too.

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting the logs before running the dalvikvm something like this 
export ANDROID_LOG_TAGS="ActivityManager:I MyApp:D *:S" the variables D -Debug S: lowest level V - verbose which is the level of log you need the application to be logged.

Answer (score 0):

`dalvikvm` is just the starter binary. The important stuff lives in `libdvm.so` so you have to build and replace this rather than `dalvikvm`.